# Codeigniter index.php error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

After removing my codeigniter project from a xampp server to a Live server i've got an error when trying to access my home page without index.php in front..

this is my route :

```
$route['home'] = 'Pages/view/home';
```

this is my config :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite/newsite';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

so when i try to surf to www.mysite/home it gives me this error :

> The requested URL /index.php/home was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

but when i surf to www.mysite/index.php/home it does work

I tried different htaccess files but without success

Comment: hi, in your htaccess you need to change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /newsite/index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @elddenmedio thanks ! worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I am on xampp with widows 10 I use these two

```
RewriteEngine on

# Next two lines get rid of trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also with your base url I would put / at the end of it

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```